# Compiling Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, tasm

I'm about to compile codes using assembly language, buy I forgot on how to compile a file to run.

Is this the correct way?

```
tasm filename
tlink /t filename.exe
```

I'm searching the web but yet I cant find the right way, would someone provide me the proper syntax for this?

Comment: [Turbo Assembler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Assembler)? Wow that is old.

Comment: Is there an error if you try it?

Comment: Yes, im still a student. Still dont know when and where to use this language, but anyway.. I might use this someday..

Comment: Yes sir Codor, and it says. "tasm" is not recognize as an internal or external command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borland's Turbo Assembler (TASM) is rather obsolete these days.  The last version update, to my knowledge, was version 5.0 with was produced about 20 years ago.

For this reason, and because your comment indicates that it's not actually installed on your machine, you would be well advised to convert to either [MASM 8.0 (Microsoft's assembler)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12654) or [NASM 2.11.06 (the Netwide Assembler)](http://www.nasm.us/) instead.  Changes to convert from TASM-specific code to run on either of the other two are usually minimal.

Comment: Some recommends me to use Virtual XP, is this really necessary? Is there any conflicts with othe flatforms?

Comment: Virtual XP is not at all necessary.  Both MASM and NASM run on the latest versions of Windows, and NASM also runs on Linux and several other platforms.

Comment: I think tasm need DOSBOX for 16 bit.

Comment: Or [FASM](http://flatassembler.net) of course, which is the better of the above mentioned.